# Problem with interactive markers example in turtlebot3

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following robotis tutorial for turtlebot3 from http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/basic_examples/

```
(turtlebot3)
$roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch  

(Remote PC)
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_remote.launch
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_example interactive_markers.launch
$ rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find turtlebot3_example`/rviz/turtlebot3_interactive.rviz
```

This is a screenshot from rviz:
[image: image description]

There are no interactive markers that I can use to move the robot. I am running ubuntu 16.04 from a VM, ros kinetic and followed the installation instructions from robotis.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300572/problem-with-interactive-markers-example-in-turtlebot3/) by [0x004](https://answers.ros.org/users/36983/0x004/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem occurs when turtlebot3 is not connected to the the remote PC or Using VM.
I recommend installing ubuntu from USB. Then, make sure remote PC's and turtlebot3's IP. This link is will help you.
http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/raspberry_pi_3_setup/#install-linux-ubuntu-mate

---

Originally posted by [Gilbert](https://answers.ros.org/users/33787/gilbert/) with karma: 41 on 2018-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0